# C++ "Virtual functions handling on multiple base classes"

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I need to derive a child class *CDerived* from two different base classes *CBaseA* and *CBaseB*.

In addition, I need to call virtual functions of both parents on the derived class. Since I want to manage differently typed objects in one single vector later (this is not part of this minimal code expample), I need to call the virtual functions from a base class pointer to the derived class object:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class CBaseA
{
  public:
    virtual void FuncA(){ std::cout << "CBaseA::FuncA()" << std::endl; };
};

class CBaseB
{
  public:
    virtual void FuncB(){ std::cout << "CBaseB::FuncB()" << std::endl; };
};

class CDerived : public CBaseB, public CBaseA
{};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  // An object of the derived type:
  CDerived oDerived;

  // A base class pointer to the object, as it could later
  // be stored in a general vector:
  CBaseA* pAHandle = reinterpret_cast<CBaseA*>( &oDerived );

  // Calling method A:
  pAHandle->FuncA();

  return 0; 
}
```

**Problem:** But when running this on my computer, *FuncB()* is called instead of *FuncA()*. I get the right result, if I "flip" the parent class deklarations around, i.e.

```
class CDerived : public CBaseA, public CBaseB
```

but this doesn't solve my problem, since I cannot be sure which function will be called.

**So my question is:** *What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way of handling such a problem?*

(I am using g++ 4.6.2, by the way)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CBaseA* pAHandle = reinterpret_cast<CBaseA*>( &oDerived );
```

Do not use `reinterpret_cast` for performing a conversion to a base class.  No cast is required; the conversion is implicit:

```
CBaseA* pAHandle = &oDerived;
```

For converting to a derived class, use `static_cast` if the object is known to be of the target type or `dynamic_cast` if it is not.

Your use of `reinterpret_cast` yields undefined behavior, hence the "odd" behavior that you see.  There are few correct uses of `reinterpret_cast` and none of them involve conversions within a class hierarchy.

Comment: In fact, there are no correct uses of reinterpret_cast that don't involve casting it back to the old type before doing anything with it.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple:  There are other valid uses.  For example, any object may be reinterpreted as an array of bytes.

Comment: I was referring to portable uses. Reinterpreting an object as an array of bytes is inherently platform-specific.

Comment: Interesting Conversions covered by the standard: 5.2.10.4 & 5: Converting a pointer to an integral type and back. 5.2.10.11: Casting a `T` object to `T&` or `T&&`. 9.2.20: "A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa." 26.4.4: Using reinterpret_cast for complex<T> types. Also 3.9.2 sort of implies (and gives reasons for) James McNellis' example.

Answer (score 2):

Common implementation which may help you to understand what happens.

CBaseA in memory look like this

```
+---------+
| __vptrA |
+---------+
```

CBaseB in memory looks like this

```
+---------+
| __vptrB |
+---------+
```

CDerived looks like this:

```
             +---------+
&oDerived->  | __vptrB |
             | __vptrA |
             +---------+
```

If you simply assign &oDerived to a CBaseA*, the compiler puts code to add the offset so that you have

```
             +---------+
&oDerived--->| __vptrB |
pAHandle---->| __vptrA |
             +---------+
```

an during execution the program find pointers to A virtual function in __vptrA. If you static_cast or dynamic_cast pAHandle back to a CDerived (or even dynamic_cast pAHandle to a CBaseA), the compiler will put code to subtract the offset so that the result point to the start of the object (dynamic_cast will find the information about how much to substract in the vtable along with the pointers to virtual functions).

When you reinterpret_casted &oDerived as a CBaseA*, the compiler don't put such code to adjust the pointer, you get

```
                       +---------+
pAHandle, &oDerived--->| __vptrB |
                       | __vptrA |
                       +---------+
```

and during the execution, the program looked at __vptrB for A virtual function, finding instead B virtual functions.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me to understand the class pointer casting issue a lot better. This piece of information is difficult to find in the internet.